# groovy Print path and value of elements in xml

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper, gpath

I have the following xml:

```
<list>         
<cars>   
<model>2012</model>
<make>GM</make>         
</cars>    
</list>
```

I want to print these values as path:value as shown below.

```
list/cars/model : 2012
list/cars/make : GM
```

How can I achieve this? I tried the `name()` method but it only prints the name of child item. I want to print the whole path till the element.

I can only use xmlSlurper parser to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried xml parser?

Comment: No, I didn't. I can only use xmlSlurper.

Answer (score 1):

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild;
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText('<root><one a1="uno!"/><two>Some text!</two></root>' )

def printMap 
printMap = {node, path->
     if(node.getClass() == NodeChild){
        node.childNodes().each{
           printMap(it, (path ? path + "/" : "") + node.name())
        }
     } else {
        println "${path}/${node.name()}:${node.text()}"
     }
 }
 printMap(rootNode, "")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sachin.

Comment: What I am also looking for is..           runAssert(root/two, otherXmlRoot/Second)     then the method is     runAssert(x, y){ assert x.text() ==y.text() : failed [ x.name(), y.name()] } So, in this method for statement x.name(), y.name() I want to print the  path. Sorry for the confusion. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
def xml = '''
<list>         
    <cars>   
        <model>2012</model>
        <make>GM</make>
        <color>Gold</color>
    </cars>    
</list>
'''

def item = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

item.'**'.inject([]) { acc, val ->
    def localText = val.localText()
    acc << val.name()

    if( localText ) {
        println "${acc.join('/')} : ${localText.join(',')}"
        acc = acc.dropRight(1) // or acc = acc[0..-2]
    } 
    acc
}
```

This would print as required. Above is using a `depthFirst()` search on the tree and using inject (just not to mutate any other list) and looks for [`localText()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChild.html#localText()). If [`localText()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChild.html#localText()) is encountered indicating the value of the leaf node, then print the path and the value. The path has been accumulated in a list which was used in inject. A simple `join()` would give the required format.

Above has been tested successfully in Groovy 2.4.5. If `localText()` is not available in `NodeChild` then a version of Groovy older than 2.3.0 would be reason because that method has been added since 2.3.0

Comment: your answer seems interesting to me. can you explain, what are you trying to do? this might be helpful for others as well... btw your code is throwing exception: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild.localText() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

Comment: I am trying to compare two elements from different xmls. Generally "assert x==y : msg" compares x &y and prints the msg if validation fails. So while printing the message I want to print the   Complete path of x and y. The method I posted above takes these arguments and returns void. So we can add void for method signature. The problems is printing the complete path

Comment: @BharathReddy *"The method I posted above takes these arguments and returns void."* I don't see any method in the question.